# How to insert URL image with JPEG extension

Tags: java, jpeg, birt, birt-deapi

How to attach image with JPEG extension using a URL? A file with extension JPG work fine in BIRT report system.

[image]

Comment: Or i must download all files and convert it?

Comment: Are you providing the whole URL or are you trying with java script? Your screenshot shows script. So did you try `row["attachments"].value` ?

Comment: yes. whole URL. All birt can't work with JPEG, but JPG work fine.

Comment: Provide following info along with your question. Are you getting any error? are you providing the whole URL starting with "http" ? are you quoting the whole URL ?

Comment: Birt not say any errors, but on render image not exists if extension JPEG. URL "https://xxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx/yyy/zzz/img-09.06.15-16.15.58.jpeg" and "https://xxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx/yyy/zzz/img-09.06.15-16.15.58.jpg"

Comment: There is no difference between JPEG and JPG - so it should work. Can you check if both images are properly accessible etc?